# RecyclerView item's button does not change button's text when click on button

Tags: android

I have implemented one code where I am using RecyclerView which Item's have 3 button and one of them is shortlist. My issue is when someone click on that button if the response is success then button text should be changed i.e shortlisted and user can not click again. I used btnShortlist.setText("shortlisted") and it's not working

Below is my class CardAdapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String url ="http://192.168.2.110/xp/shortlist1.php";
private static final String url1 = "http://192.168.2.110/xp/express_intrest.php";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_TO="matriID_to";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_BY="matriID_by";

SessionManager session;
public String matri_id_to, matri_id_by, str_gender;
String str;

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

//List to store all superheroes
List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    matri_id_by = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    str_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    final SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewId.setText(superHero.getMglId());
    holder.AgeHeight.setText(superHero.getAgeHeight()+" / "+superHero.getAge());
    holder.Community.setText(superHero.getCommunity()+" / "+superHero.getCaste());
    holder.Occupation.setText(superHero.getOccupation());
    holder.Income.setText(superHero.getIncome());
 //   holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
 //   holder.btnEI.setText(superHero.getExpress_Intrest());

    str = superHero.getShortlist();
    Log.e("sh____________",str);
    if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("shortlisted")) {
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
        holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));
        holder.btnShortlist.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
    }

    holder.btnShortlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.btnShortlist.setText("Wait...");
            matri_id_to = superHero.getMglId();
            holder.shortlist(position);

        }
    });

    holder.btnViewProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent n = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),BlankActivity.class);
            String str_id = holder.textViewId.getText().toString();
            n.putExtra("ID",str_id);
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(n);
        }
    });


    holder.btnEI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return superHeroes.size();}
```

Class ViewHolder

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewId;
    public TextView AgeHeight;
    public TextView Community;
    public TextView Occupation;
    public TextView Income;
    public Button btnShortlist;
    public Button btnViewProfile;
    public Button btnEI;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
        textViewId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        AgeHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AgeHeight);
        Community = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Community);
        Occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Occupation);
        Income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Income);
        btnShortlist = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
        btnViewProfile = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewProfile);
        btnEI = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnExpressIntrest);
    }
```

method for shortlist

```
    private void shortlist(final int position){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    int selectedPosition = position;
                    btnShortlist.setText("shortlisted");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: is shortlist is an interface method? do you have access to the btnShortList from there? where is your shortlist method declared?

Comment: what is the return type of  `superHero.getShortlist()` method  list or just string?

Comment: @Roljhon no shortlist is not interface method. I declared shortlist on ViewHolder class please check that

Comment: @Bek that is String

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the state of the button that which is clicked on specific Row. Like on Button click you have to update data on SuperHero model and notify data set change.

Add below method in your RecyclerView's Adapter.

```
 public SuperHero getItem(int position){
    return superHeroes.get(position);
}
```

and your onResponse(String response)   method look like below.

```
  if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
        SuperHero superhero = adapter.getItem(position);
        superhero.setShortlist("shortlisted");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

where adapter is your RecyclerViewAdapter's instance.

Comment: what is adapter on here

Comment: CardAdapter's instance

Comment: Wait!!!  Could you please show me code where you setAdapter is written ?

Comment: when I am using public SuperHero getItem(int position){
    return superHeroes.get(position);
}  item is not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160508/discussion-between-user6734679-and-ammy).

Comment: where should I add adapter